# MYSQL create stored procedure included DELETE, SELECT and INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I read manuals, I can create simply stored procedure.
Its work fine. But now I need to create complicated for me procedure included DELETE, SELECT and INSERT

First:

```
delete from 111test;
```

Next:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_nickname, u.country_id, u.city_id, u.avatar_id,
  (SELECT name FROM countries WHERE id = u.country_id) country_name,
  (SELECT name FROM cities WHERE id = u.city_id) city_name
FROM users_onsite uo 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = uo.user_id
WHERE u.avatar_id > 0;
```

And next:

```
INSERT INTO 111test (type,user_id,some_datas1,some_datas2,some_datas3) 
  values (53,$user_id,'$user_nickname',$country_name','$city_name')
```

So, my procedure is:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE var_user_id INT(50);
DECLARE var_some_datas1 varchar(255);
DECLARE var_some_datas2 varchar(255);
DECLARE var_some_datas3 varchar(255);

delete from 111test;

SELECT u.user_id, u.user_nickname, u.country_id, u.city_id, u.avatar_id,
  (SELECT name FROM countries WHERE id = u.country_id) country_name,
  (SELECT name FROM cities WHERE id = u.city_id) city_name
  FROM users_onsite uo 
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = uo.user_id
  WHERE u.avatar_id > 0;

INSERT INTO  111test (type,user_id,some_datas1,some_datas2,some_datas3)
  VALUES (53,var_user_id,var_some_datas1,var_some_datas2,var_some_datas3);

END
```

Result: Your SQL query has been executed successfully 1172 rows affected by the last statement inside the procedure

But Inserted ZERO rows in table 111test.

Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what's the road block here. You can create procedure which include DML operations. See a sample below (though created in SQL Server)

```
create procedure sp_crud_test
as
begin
delete from sample1;

select * from sample3;

insert into sample1 select * from sample3;
end

exec sp_crud_test
```

So in your case it would be something like

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_crud_test (IN 
user_id int, IN user_nickname varchar(10),
IN country_name varchar(10),IN city_name varchar(10))
BEGIN
delete from 111test;

SELECT u.user_id, u.user_nickname, u.country_id, u.city_id, u.avatar_id,
  (SELECT name FROM countries WHERE id = u.country_id) country_name,
  (SELECT name FROM cities WHERE id = u.city_id) city_name
FROM users_onsite uo 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = uo.user_id
WHERE u.avatar_id > 0;

INSERT INTO 111test (type,user_id,some_datas1,some_datas2,some_datas3) 
  values (53,user_id,user_nickname,country_name,city_name)
END//
```

Than call it like

```
CALL sp_crud_test(10,'tk','US','london')
```

**EDIT:**
Now I got, you are trying to insert your select query values to that table; which should be done like below

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_crud_test
BEGIN
delete from 111test;

INSERT INTO 111test (type,user_id,some_datas1,some_datas2,some_datas3) 
SELECT '53' as type, u.user_id, u.user_nickname,
  (SELECT name FROM countries WHERE id = u.country_id) country_name,
  (SELECT name FROM cities WHERE id = u.city_id) city_name
FROM users_onsite uo 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = uo.user_id
WHERE u.avatar_id > 0;    
END//
```

Then just call like

```
CALL sp_crud_test
```

Comment: Yes, I already try like your. 

Result:
Your SQL query has been executed successfully
1172 rows affected by the last statement inside the procedure

But Inserted ZERO rows in table 111test. 

I add: 

DECLARE var_user_id INT(11);
DECLARE var_some_datas1 INT(11);
DECLARE var_some_datas2 INT(11);
DECLARE var_some_datas3 INT(11);

But result the same.

Comment: @TKVideoChat, see edited answer now. You need to pass the parameters to procedure.

Comment: When I try to create procedure, I get an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@user_id int, IN @user_nickname varchar(10),
IN @country_name varchar(10),IN @c' at line 2 `

Comment: @TKVideoChat, use the edited SP. problem was with `@` sign in parameter which is used for global variable.

Comment: Now it work. I make a `CALL sp_crud_test(10,'tk','US','london')` but to table **111test** inserted 1 row with: **10,'tk','US','london'** instead of 1473 my rows.

Comment: @TKVideoChat, that's correct. how it will insert 1473 rows; you are having only one insert statement and so only 1 row getting inserted.

Comment: @TKVideoChat, see edited answer again. You should clarify everything in your question.